# How to select multiple components of Canvas using ctrl key in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I want to select few images available on my Canvas. How to select multiple of them using control key?

Answer (score 11):

You create a model, e. g.

```
List<Node> selectionModel = new ArrayList<Node>();
```

and add a listener to each node, e. g.

```
        imageView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {

            if( event.isControlDown()) {
                selectionModel.add( (Node) event.getSource());

                // logging
                System.out.println("Items in model:");
                selectionModel.forEach(n -> System.out.println(n));
            }

        });
```

Of course you need to provide an option to clear the selection model, e. g. by clicking outside on the scene instead of an ImageView.

---

Here's a more sophisticated example. Supports rubberband selection, ctrl for selection toggle, shift for adding to selection and click on background to clear the selection.

```
public class ImageSelection extends Application {


    Image image = new Image("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg/320px-Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg");

    SelectionModel selectionModel = new SelectionModel();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Pane pane = new Pane();

        double width = image.getWidth();
        double height = image.getHeight();

        double padding = 20;
        for( int row=0; row < 4; row++) {
            for( int col=0; col < 4; col++) {

                ImageView imageView = new ImageView( image);
                imageView.relocate( padding * (col+1) + width * col, padding * (row + 1) + height * row);

                pane.getChildren().add(imageView);

            }
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene( pane, 1800, 1200);

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();        

        new RubberBandSelection( pane);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class SelectionModel {

        Set<Node> selection = new HashSet<>();

        public void add( Node node) {
            node.setStyle("-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, red, 10, 10, 0, 0);");
            selection.add( node);
        }

        public void remove( Node node) {
            node.setStyle("-fx-effect: null");
            selection.remove( node);
        }

        public void clear() {

            while( !selection.isEmpty()) {
                remove( selection.iterator().next());
            }

        }

        public boolean contains( Node node) {
            return selection.contains(node);
        }

        public void log() {
            System.out.println( "Items in model: " + Arrays.asList( selection.toArray()));
        }

    }

    private class RubberBandSelection {

        final DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();
        Rectangle rect;

        Pane group;

        public RubberBandSelection( Pane group) {

            this.group = group;

            rect = new Rectangle( 0,0,0,0);
            rect.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            rect.setStrokeWidth(1);
            rect.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
            rect.setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE.deriveColor(0, 1.2, 1, 0.6));

            group.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, onMousePressedEventHandler);
            group.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, onMouseDraggedEventHandler);
            group.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, onMouseReleasedEventHandler);

        }

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                dragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
                dragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();

                rect.setX(dragContext.mouseAnchorX);
                rect.setY(dragContext.mouseAnchorY);
                rect.setWidth(0);
                rect.setHeight(0);

                group.getChildren().add( rect);

                event.consume();

            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                if( !event.isShiftDown() && !event.isControlDown()) {
                    selectionModel.clear();
                }

                for( Node node: group.getChildren()) {

                    if( node instanceof ImageView) {
                        if( node.getBoundsInParent().intersects( rect.getBoundsInParent())) {

                            if( event.isShiftDown()) {

                                selectionModel.add( node);

                            } else if( event.isControlDown()) {

                                if( selectionModel.contains( node)) {
                                    selectionModel.remove( node);
                                } else {
                                    selectionModel.add( node);
                                }
                            } else {
                                selectionModel.add( node);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

                selectionModel.log();

                rect.setX(0);
                rect.setY(0);
                rect.setWidth(0);
                rect.setHeight(0);

                group.getChildren().remove( rect);

                event.consume();

            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                double offsetX = event.getSceneX() - dragContext.mouseAnchorX;
                double offsetY = event.getSceneY() - dragContext.mouseAnchorY;

                if( offsetX > 0)
                    rect.setWidth( offsetX);
                else {
                    rect.setX(event.getSceneX());
                    rect.setWidth(dragContext.mouseAnchorX - rect.getX());
                }

                if( offsetY > 0) {
                    rect.setHeight( offsetY);
                } else {
                    rect.setY(event.getSceneY());
                    rect.setHeight(dragContext.mouseAnchorY - rect.getY());
                }

                event.consume();

            }
        };

        private final class DragContext {

            public double mouseAnchorX;
            public double mouseAnchorY;


        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer if your images to be selected are nodes in the [scene graph](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1106328); e.g., the parent of the nodes is a [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) rather than [the images being drawn directly on to the graphics context](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#drawImage-javafx.scene.image.Image-double-double-) of a [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html).

Comment: Yes, I wrote it under the assumption that he's new and didn't mean "Canvas" as JavaFX Canvas, because otherwise I'd have to ask "Why would you do that?". If it's not what he's after, he can always ignore my answer or say that it's not what he's looking for.

Comment: It works good if you select elements added to Pane.  If you have tiles in TilePane add Rectangle to parent node and use getX/getY instead of getSceneX/getSceneY.